# Disabling ArrowUp and ArrowDown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I would like to prevent the ArrowUp and ArrowDown keys in an input field, so that these keys do not change the input value. Is it possible? How could I do it? I am using React.

The only thing I tried was:

```
function onKeyPressRegex(e) {
  if (!/[0-9]/.test(e.key) || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}

<input
 onKeyPress={(e) => onKeyPressRegex(e)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on what you mean by changing the input value, but the normal behaviour of the up and down arrow keys is to go to the beginning or end of the text box.

In pure JavaScript, you can listen for the `keydown` or `keyup` event (`keypress` has been deprecated).

The event listener function includes a paramater, here called `event`, which contains a `key` property which has the name of the key. In modern JavaScript, the names of the arrow keys are called `ArrowUp` and `ArrowDown`.

In the sample code, I simply test the key name against these two values and, if it matches, use `event.prevenDefault()` to stop the normal behaviour.

```js
let theForm = document.querySelector('form#test');
theForm.elements['textbox'].onkeydown = function(event) {
  if(event.key == 'ArrowUp' || event.key == 'ArrowDown') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="test">
  <input type="text" name="textbox">
</form>
enter code here
```

Comment: The numeric input had its value changed when pressing arrowUp, and I would like to prevent this. Creating a separate function and putting it in an onKeyDown event, as suggested, worked, thank you.